# Error while building CoinOR

Tags: coin-or-cbc

I'm trying to build CoinOR and I'm following the simple instructions on https://projects.coin-or.org/CoinBinary. Configuration is successful, so I should have all dependencies. But I come accross this error while running the 'make' command:

> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.
>
> -I/home/user/CoinOR/COIN-1.8/Osi/src/Osi -I/home/user/CoinOR/COIN-1.8/CoinUtils/src -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-long-long -DFLOPCPP_BUILD -MT MP_boolean.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/MP_boolean.Tpo -c MP_boolean.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/MP_boolean.o In file included from MP_boolean.cpp:12:
>
> MP_set.hpp: In member function 'flopc::MP_domain&
>
> flopc::MP_subset::operator()(const flopc::SUBSETREF&)':
>
> MP_set.hpp:212:9: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of
>
> type 'flopc::MP_domain&' to an rvalue of type 'flopc::MP_domain'
>
> return MP_domain(s);
>
> ```
>      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Does someone have an id or a solution, like just precompiled binaries? I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use? Cbc (and it's dependencies)?  Or what else? Your link includes binaries.

Comment: I'm using the 'OptimizationSuite' from the svn. I think it includes everything... I'm just following the instructions in 'Building from Source'.

What I want to do is optimize a linear model in C# (or java).

Comment: This suite is huge and some projects might be in a bad shape. I mentioned those binaries available and as seen, those are from 2015 (an indication of: building everything is hard). Now: how would you use those projects from C#/java? Linear Model means Linear Programming? This is all very unclear. If you just need an LP or MIP solver, go to the specific project (LP: Clp; MIP: Cbc; the latter subsumes the former) and build this including it's dependencies (e.g. CoinUtils). This is not that hard (ignoring your C#/Java). A basic template is [here](https://github.com/h-g-s/lp/issues/1)

Comment: If your usage is cli-based, you can find recent binaries [here](https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source/). (people behind it have a lot of CoinOR insight). But i doubt those will help in cases, where some library-usage is needed (check yourself if those only provide the cli-solvers or also shared-libs: you can pick Cbc for LPs and MIPs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes. I mean linear programming. I have both boolean and integer variables in my model. Any good links for installing any of the packages? The links on the coin-or project homepage seem to be broken.

Comment: Bool and Int is not LP anymore, but (Mixed-)Integer-Programming (Clp not enough; Cbc is needed). I gave you a link describing the simple install. You just have to modify that for your system (it's ubuntu based; but changes should be trivial). This includes a link to Cbc's SVN trunk. The binaries work too. But still... not sure how you would use those (C++ based projects). The Cbc-enty on CoinORs website is [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc).

Comment: I've successfully installed CBC. Do you accidentaly have a tutorial how to use this library in java or c#? All I can find is c++ examples, but they don't really seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the return type of the function on line 212 of the file MP_set.hpp.

```
MP_domain& operator()(const SUBSETREF& s) {
    return MP_domain(s);
}
```

becomes

```
MP_domain operator()(const SUBSETREF& s) {
    return MP_domain(s);
}
```